# How to decrypt segmented parts .ts files which are encrypted with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I use ffmpeg to generate encrypted m3u8 playlists, both generation and playing work perfectly.

The statement I use to generate m3u8:

```
ffmpg -i "source.mp4"  -c:v h264_nvenc 
 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod
 -hls_key_info_file "d:\enc.keyinfo" -hls_segment_filename "output_$03d.ts" "output.m3u8";
```

Content of d:\enc.keyinfo:

```
/enc.key
d:\enc.key
261daad184c6acf4a3a21393ds232e1a
```

Now I need to decrypt one or more generated .ts segments (not the whole m3u8 playlist), what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to do it manually you can just use `openssl`

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in encrypted.ts -out decrypted.ts -nosalt -K 261daad184c6acf4a3a21393ds232e1a -iv <iv>
```

To do so you also need to get the IV from your `output.m3u8` playlist file. It is a property on the `#EXT-X-KEY` tag in there. If it is not explicitly specified on that tag, then it is implicitly `0` for the first segment, `1` for the second, and so on.

Comment: What exactly did you use as IV? Did you omit the `0x` at the beginning?

Comment: I removed `0x` now it seems different. it says `bad decrypt`, and I got `decrypted.ts` in a normal size, but it can't be played in any software :(

Comment: The detailed response is `bad decrypt
140346049500480:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:583:`

Comment: Can you double-check that the hex string for the key you are using is correct? Maybe create it again from the key file using `hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' enc.key`

Comment: Yes, I checked at least 5 times, the -K parameter is the string in the `enc.keyinfo`, and the iv is that in the .m3u8 file. As for ` hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' enc.key`, what does it mean and where should I use it? Sorry I have no experience in encryption and my questions are naive

Comment: `#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="/inc/enc.key",IV=0x067209a194b6ab5482af9c937c264eaa`
It's the related info in the m3u8 file, mayble it's useful to locate the issue

Comment: I found the iv in the m3u8 file is exactly same with that in enc.keyinfo, I found another post, it says should use `xxd -p enc.key` to get the iv, I tired but get same result `bad decrypt`

Comment: Finally I made it! `openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in encrypted.ts -out decrypted.ts -nosalt -K <k> -iv <iv>`
-K: get from using `xxd -p enc.key`
-iv: in the `.keyinfo` or `.m3u8`

Comment: Nice, exactly! Btw, just to clarify `hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"' enc.key` and `xxd -p enc.key` are equivalent commands and yield the same result. Admittedly, the `xxd` one is easier/shorter :)